# Getting latest post ID not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress

I've trying to get the latest post ID in WordPress, but the two different methods I am using are returning different results.

FYI if I look in PHPmyAdmin I can see the latest post ID is 3000.

If I do this...

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'any'
);
$the_ID = get_posts($args);
$latest_ID = $the_ID[0]->ID;
echo $latest_ID;
```

...it returns 2999 instead of 3000. This is very odd.

But if I specify some post types in an array like this...

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => array('post', 'page', 'attachment')
);
$the_ID = get_posts($args);
$latest_ID = $the_ID[0]->ID;
echo $latest_ID;
```

...it returns 3000 which is the correct ID but also not very maintainable.

My understanding is that 'post_type' => 'any' should include all post types, and obviously I don't want to use the 2nd method because I'd have to update the array manually every time there is a new post type.

Is there a way around this? Or perhaps a better way of getting the latest post ID?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code **100%** working and tested:

**Note:** When you register new post type then automatically will be add in below conditions.

```
function get_all_custom_post_types() {
    $args = array( 'public' => true );
    $output = 'objects'; //'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
    $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
    $custom_post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );           
    $post_types = array();
    foreach ( $custom_post_types as $k => $post_type ) {
        $post_types[] = $post_type->name;
    }           
    return $post_types;
}

//print_r(get_all_custom_post_types()); // Array ( [0] => post [1] => page [2] => attachment [3] => product [4] => movies )

$args = array(
    'post_type' => get_all_custom_post_types(),
    'posts_per_page'  => 10
);

$latest_cpt = get_posts($args );
//print_r($latest_cpt);
echo $latest_cpt[0]->ID;
```

Comment: That's almost the same as the 2nd method I posted, but as mentioned it's not very maintainable. If a new post type is added (say from activating a new plugin that creates a new post type), then I would have to find out what the post type is an add it into the array.

I didn't realise it was common knowledge that  'post_type' => 'any' doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for the effort. The solution was easier than I thought, and technically there was nothing 'broken' in the first place. See my answer. It turns out 'post_type' => 'any' works just fine assuming all post types are publicly query-able.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...

The post type of one of my plugins was not public. I changed it from false to true...

```
'public' => true
```

...and now if I use 'post_type' => 'any' it works fine.